# Installing/configuring mysql server nightmare

Tags: 10.10, mysql, kubuntu

I've never had problems installing and configuring mysql server in kubuntu but now it's just being stubborn, here's my issue:

I installed the packages `mysql-server`, `mysql-client (both 5.1)`, the server package asked me to put a root password, which I did, it then started saying "access denied", on anything

Later on, I decided to purge the packages and re-install and gave a tweak to the `my.cnf` and not it says

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Please, is there a way to do a fresh start on this and do it right this time? I don't know if I'm missing something but the `/var/lib/mysql is not empty` but there is no .pid, now the mysql service won't start, there is no `mysql.sock` either

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To perform a clean reinstall:

```
sudo killall mysqld    
sudo apt-get purge mysql-common
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Then

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter the configured password.

Comment: The Mysql-common package wants to remove a lot of packages =/

Comment: mysql-common is reponsible for the default /etc/mysql, "sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-common" might also work, but my experience with a similar problem was to remove/install the package after manually editing /etc/mysql/* .

Comment: It didn't work, still claiming that there is no mysql.sock

Comment: Did you follow the entire procedure ? Dit it ask for a password during the mysql-server install ?

Comment: Yes, I followed it throughly, it also deleted all the my.cnf so when I tried to start the mysql server it rejected it since it had no direction whatsoever, so I decided to search for the default my.cnf and got it working completely, currently logged in mysql console with the root user, phew, thanks a lot for your help! (summary: my.cnf was missing so it didn't start) created it in /etc/mysql and type `sudo start mysql` it started with no problem :)

Comment: Dang, so glad I found this. Had the exact same problem.